# Is it possible to use Avro with Hadoop 0.20?

Tags: api, hadoop, hdfs

I'm interested in using Avro to save and read files from Hadoop HDFS and I saw some Jira's in Hadoop issue tracker regarding implementing support for Avro but there were no examples how to enable Avro support in Hadoop. Also I'm not completely sure that current 0.20 has support for Avro because some Jira's were closed for 0.21. Is it possible to get latest 0.21 and end somehow turn on Avro and use it?

Answer (score 3):

This blog post shows some example code for using Avro in Map/Reduce Jobs: http://www.datasalt.com/2011/07/hadoop-avro/ There aren't many examples out there. Here you'll find some code snippets on how to configure a standard Map/Reduce Job for using Avro either as input or output format or both. There are also some tricks like how to write a custom GroupComparator for secondary sorting or how to specify a custom Partitioner (things which I haven't found anywhere else).

Answer (score 0):

I am using Avro with Hadoop 0.20 (Amazon Elastic MapReduce). You enable Avro support by including the Avro jar in your classpath, then extending Avro provided classes to implement your Map and Reduce tasks.

See http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/index.html and particularly the mapred package at http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/avro/mapred/package-frame.html .